# Android Studio How do I get my Bottom navigation view to show my menu

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Im trying to get my material Bottom Navigation bar to show up but whenever i add " app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" " to my acitivty_main.xml, the Navigation bar disappears. How do I fix this?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="Favorites"
        android:visible="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_steps"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_steps"
        android:title="Steps"
        android:visible="true"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. When i take away the app:menu part it shows a black navigation bar but as soon as I add the menu, the navigation bar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set background color to bottomnavigation menu.
try adding
**android:background="?android:attr/windowBackgroud"** in your bottomnavigation menu.